# Need to convert a string to Json Object in scala

Tags: json, scala

I am trying to convert a string to JSON using JSON spray. But I am very new in scala and facing trouble to write the code. My input file is a string and may contain more element.

Example input String

```
12 rob 133 millan
```

Expected JSON file is below

```
[
  {
    "M": {
      "Score": {
        "N": "12"
      },
      "TopicID": {
        "S": "rob"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "M": {
      "Score": {
        "N": "133"
      },
      "TopicID": {
        "S": "milan"
      }
    }
  }
```

Any suggestion toward code approach would help as well.
Please suggest.

Comment: So one string actually resolves in an array of objects?

Comment: yes, but i am not sure how to design it. in that particular json schema

Comment: I would probably first parse the input string into my own representation (case classes or something) and then use Spray Json to encode that into valid JSON.

Comment: Sounds like you just need a custom serializer here given that you only need to inject a small subset of the data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regards of creating the json:

First, you need to define the case class:

```
case class SClass(S: string)
case class NClass(N: string)
case class MClass(Score: NClass, TopicID: SClass)
```

Then:

```
implicit val mclassFormat = jsonFormat2(MClass)
implicit val nclassFormat = jsonFormat(NClass)
implicit val sclassFormat = jsonFormat(SClass)

// serialize the json (hardcoded values)
val mClass = MClass(NClass(12.toString(), SClass("rob"))
val mClassJsonString = mClass.toJson.prettyPrint
```

About parsing your input:

```
 val input = "12 rob 13 bla"

 val a = input.split(" ").zipWithIndex.collect{case(v,i) if (i % 2 == 0) => 
 (v,i)}.map(_._1)
 val b = input.split(" ").zipWithIndex.collect{case(v,i) if (i % 2 != 0) => 
 (v,i)}.map(_._1)
 val result = a.zip(b) // [(12,rob),(13,bla)]
```

now you can traverse on your result like this:

```
 result.foreach{case (x,y) => 
      val mClass = MClass(NClass(x.toString(), SClass(y))
      val mClassJsonString = mClass.toJson.prettyPrint
 }
```

Comment: The above query worked like charm. however is there any way I can use mclassJsonString outside the for loop, I need to write the msclassJsonString in a file and morever i am planning to use the same design in other project as well .